Why is my Tradingview indicator displaying different results depending on my charts timeframe?
So the indicator basically grabs the current and previous high and low for each timeframe selected for each symbol imputed. (I do some timeframe mapping for the strategy as you will see in the code).
It then does some math to show if 1 or 2 of the symbols has a current high that is higher then its previous high for that timeframe or a current low that is lower then the previous low for that timeframe. for example, if for NQ1!, ES1! and YM1! only ES1! and YM1! has a current 6H (360min) high that is higher then the previous 6H high, it'll show as "Active" on the table.
It is working as intended for each timeframe (90min, 360min, D, W) EXCEPT the yearly cycle selection (3M timeframe). When I have the Yearly Selected (3M timeframe). It will only show as Active on the 3M timeframe or higher on my chart. If I am on any timeframe lower on my chart, it will not show as "Active" when it should.
I've tried using the barmerge.lookahead on and off in the request.security funtion for fetching the current and previous candle high and low for the selected timeframes and still getting the same issue. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Current Code:
//@version=5
indicator("Sequential SMT (QT)", overlay=true)
//@description SSMT indicator

// Input: Symbols selection
selectedSymbol1 = input.symbol("CME_MINI:NQ1!", "Symbol 1")
selectedSymbol2 = input.symbol("CME_MINI:ES1!", "Symbol 2")
selectedSymbol3 = input.symbol("CBOT_MINI:YM1!", "Symbol 3")  // Added third symbol

// Input: Timeframe selection
selectedTimeframe1 = input.string("Yearly", "Cycle 1", options=["Yearly", "Monthly", "Weekly", "Daily", "90min"])
selectedTimeframe2 = input.string("Monthly", "Cycle 2", options=["Yearly", "Monthly", "Weekly", "Daily", "90min"])
selectedTimeframe3 = input.string("Weekly", "Cycle 3", options=["Yearly", "Monthly", "Weekly", "Daily", "90min"])

// Input: Table position
tablePosition = input.string("top_left", "Display Results", options=["top_left", "top_right", "bottom_left", "bottom_right", "center"])

// Function to map the selected timeframe to the appropriate timeframe and string for the request.security functions
mapTimeframe(selected) =>
    if selected == "Yearly"
        "3M"
    else if selected == "Monthly"
        "W"
    else if selected == "Weekly"
        "D"
    else if selected == "Daily"
        "360"
    else if selected == "90min"
        "90"
    else
        "D"  // default to Daily if no match

// Function to get the current high and low for the specific symbol and timeframe
getHighLow(symbol, timeframe) =>
    highValue = request.security(symbol, mapTimeframe(timeframe), high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
    lowValue = request.security(symbol, mapTimeframe(timeframe), low, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
    [highValue, lowValue]

// Function to get previous high and low for the specific symbol and timeframe
getPrevHighLow(symbol, timeframe) =>
    prevHighValue = request.security(symbol, mapTimeframe(timeframe), high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
    prevLowValue = request.security(symbol, mapTimeframe(timeframe), low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
    [prevHighValue, prevLowValue]

// Get current high and low for each symbol and timeframe
[currentHighSymbol1Timeframe1, currentLowSymbol1Timeframe1] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol1, selectedTimeframe1)
[currentHighSymbol1Timeframe2, currentLowSymbol1Timeframe2] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol1, selectedTimeframe2)
[currentHighSymbol1Timeframe3, currentLowSymbol1Timeframe3] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol1, selectedTimeframe3)

[currentHighSymbol2Timeframe1, currentLowSymbol2Timeframe1] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol2, selectedTimeframe1)
[currentHighSymbol2Timeframe2, currentLowSymbol2Timeframe2] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol2, selectedTimeframe2)
[currentHighSymbol2Timeframe3, currentLowSymbol2Timeframe3] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol2, selectedTimeframe3)

[currentHighSymbol3Timeframe1, currentLowSymbol3Timeframe1] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol3, selectedTimeframe1)
[currentHighSymbol3Timeframe2, currentLowSymbol3Timeframe2] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol3, selectedTimeframe2)
[currentHighSymbol3Timeframe3, currentLowSymbol3Timeframe3] = getHighLow(selectedSymbol3, selectedTimeframe3)

// Get previous high and low for each symbol and timeframe
[prevHighSymbol1Timeframe1, prevLowSymbol1Timeframe1] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol1, selectedTimeframe1)
[prevHighSymbol1Timeframe2, prevLowSymbol1Timeframe2] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol1, selectedTimeframe2)
[prevHighSymbol1Timeframe3, prevLowSymbol1Timeframe3] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol1, selectedTimeframe3)

[prevHighSymbol2Timeframe1, prevLowSymbol2Timeframe1] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol2, selectedTimeframe1)
[prevHighSymbol2Timeframe2, prevLowSymbol2Timeframe2] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol2, selectedTimeframe2)
[prevHighSymbol2Timeframe3, prevLowSymbol2Timeframe3] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol2, selectedTimeframe3)

[prevHighSymbol3Timeframe1, prevLowSymbol3Timeframe1] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol3, selectedTimeframe1)
[prevHighSymbol3Timeframe2, prevLowSymbol3Timeframe2] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol3, selectedTimeframe2)
[prevHighSymbol3Timeframe3, prevLowSymbol3Timeframe3] = getPrevHighLow(selectedSymbol3, selectedTimeframe3)

// SSMT detection for timeframe 1's highs on each symbol
countHigherTimeframe1 = (currentHighSymbol1Timeframe1 > prevHighSymbol1Timeframe1 ? 1 : 0) + (currentHighSymbol2Timeframe1 > prevHighSymbol2Timeframe1 ? 1 : 0) + (currentHighSymbol3Timeframe1 > prevHighSymbol3Timeframe1 ? 1 : 0)
// SSMT detection for timeframe 1's lows on each symbol
countLowerTimeframe1 = (currentLowSymbol1Timeframe1 < prevLowSymbol1Timeframe1 ? 1 : 0) + (currentLowSymbol2Timeframe1 < prevLowSymbol2Timeframe1 ? 1 : 0) + (currentLowSymbol3Timeframe1 < prevLowSymbol3Timeframe1 ? 1 : 0)
// SSMT detection for timeframe 2's highs on each symbol
countHigherTimeframe2 = (currentHighSymbol1Timeframe2 > prevHighSymbol1Timeframe2 ? 1 : 0) + (currentHighSymbol2Timeframe2 > prevHighSymbol2Timeframe2 ? 1 : 0) + (currentHighSymbol3Timeframe2 > prevHighSymbol3Timeframe2 ? 1 : 0)
// SSMT detection for timeframe 2's lows on each symbol
countLowerTimeframe2 = (currentLowSymbol1Timeframe2 < prevLowSymbol1Timeframe2 ? 1 : 0) + (currentLowSymbol2Timeframe2 < prevLowSymbol2Timeframe2 ? 1 : 0) + (currentLowSymbol3Timeframe2 < prevLowSymbol3Timeframe2 ? 1 : 0)
// SSMT detection for timeframe 3's highs on each symbol
countHigherTimeframe3 = (currentHighSymbol1Timeframe3 > prevHighSymbol1Timeframe3 ? 1 : 0) + (currentHighSymbol2Timeframe3 > prevHighSymbol2Timeframe3 ? 1 : 0) + (currentHighSymbol3Timeframe3 > prevHighSymbol3Timeframe3 ? 1 : 0)
// SSMT detection for timeframe 3's lows on each symbol
countLowerTimeframe3 = (currentLowSymbol1Timeframe3 < prevLowSymbol1Timeframe3 ? 1 : 0) + (currentLowSymbol2Timeframe3 < prevLowSymbol2Timeframe3 ? 1 : 0) + (currentLowSymbol3Timeframe3 < prevLowSymbol3Timeframe3 ? 1 : 0)

// Create a table
var table myTable = table.new(tablePosition, 3, 6, border_color=#000000, border_width=1)

// Set table title
if bar_index == 0
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 0, "SSMT Detection for", bgcolor=#b2b5be, text_color = #000000)
    table.merge_cells(myTable, 0, 0, 2, 0)

// Set header with symbols currently
if bar_index == 0
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 0, "Sequential SMT", bgcolor=#b2b5be, text_color = #000000)
    table.merge_cells(myTable, 0, 0, 2, 0)

// Set headers for the table
if bar_index == 0
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 1, "Cycles", bgcolor=#000000, text_color = #ffffff)
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 1, "Bullish", bgcolor=#ffffff, text_color = #000000)
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 1, "Bearish", bgcolor=#ffffff, text_color = #000000)
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 2, selectedTimeframe1, bgcolor=#ffffff, text_color = #000000)
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 3, selectedTimeframe2, bgcolor=#ffffff, text_color = #000000)
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 4, selectedTimeframe3, bgcolor=#ffffff, text_color = #000000)

// Output results for timeframes 1 high (bearish) on each symbol
if countHigherTimeframe1 > 0 and countHigherTimeframe1 < 3
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 2, "Active", bgcolor=#68eb8f, text_color = #000000)
else
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 2, "Inactive", bgcolor=#e05757, text_color = #000000)

// Output results for timeframes 1 low (bullish) on each symbol
if countLowerTimeframe1 > 0 and countLowerTimeframe1 < 3
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 2, "Active", bgcolor=#68eb8f, text_color = #000000)
else
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 2, "Inactive", bgcolor=#e05757, text_color = #000000)

// Output results for timeframes 2 high (bearish) on each symbol
if countHigherTimeframe2 > 0 and countHigherTimeframe2 < 3
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 3, "Active", bgcolor=#68eb8f, text_color = #000000)
else
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 3, "Inactive", bgcolor=#e05757, text_color = #000000)

// Output results for timeframes 2 low (bullish) on each symbol
if countLowerTimeframe2 > 0 and countLowerTimeframe2 < 3
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 3, "Active", bgcolor=#68eb8f, text_color = #000000)
else
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 3, "Inactive", bgcolor=#e05757, text_color = #000000)

// Output results for timeframes 3 high (bearish) on each symbol
if countHigherTimeframe3 > 0 and countHigherTimeframe3 < 3
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 4, "Active", bgcolor=#68eb8f, text_color = #000000)
else
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 4, "Inactive", bgcolor=#e05757, text_color = #000000)

// Output results for timeframes 3 low (bullish) on each symbol
if countLowerTimeframe3 > 0 and countLowerTimeframe3 < 3
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 4, "Active", bgcolor=#68eb8f, text_color = #000000)
else
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 4, "Inactive", bgcolor=#e05757, text_color = #000000)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
